# Can a piezo actuator have infinite resolution?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, error-analysis, piezoelectric

See here:

http://www.omega.com/googlebase/product.html?pn=LD400-1&gclid=CjwKEAjw77OhBRCJ7Onfp_HNtwYSJACZqHAWVTfW1BO4RSfSVjz9P3Q4FoPTvZ2r3NIc2W1uEthVhBoCgUHw_wcB

I don't think so.  Do they just mean it's probably accurate enough for most applications?

Comment: You might want to change the title to "Can a LVDT have infinite resolution" since that is what your link refers to.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Infinite resolution" simply means, in this context, that it has a linear (analog) output - one that in principle changes for even the smallest change in position of the actuator. Contrast this with a transducer that produces an output in discrete steps - for example an optical encoder.

Quoting from http://www.macrosensors.com/lvdt_tutorial.html :

> **Infinite Resolution**
>   Since an LVDT operates on electromagnetic coupling principles in a friction-free structure, it can measure infinitesimally small changes in core position. This infinite resolution capability is limited only by the noise in an LVDT signal conditioner and the output display's resolution. These same factors also give an LVDT its outstanding repeatability.

What precision you can obtain depends on how accurately you control the excitation voltage and how accurately you measure the response. There are other subtle effects that play a role as well. See the above link for more information.

Note, incidentally, that it is NOT a piezo-electric transducer. Piezo-electronics refers to a different physical mechanism entirely, in which stress on a material produces a corresponding voltage. This is used in electronic lighters and such. The link you provided is for a LVDT - Linear Variable Differential Transformer. A completely different beast.

Answer (score 1):

I think infinite resolution assumes that you have infinitely precise voltage. The chip is infinitely precise in response, but the harder job is to have the voltage so stable to make use of that resolution.

Another possibility is that within other characteristics the resolution could be infinite. For example, in some statistical limit calculation you can increase the bandwidth to infinity $\Delta f \rightarrow \infty$, which is infinite frequency resolution, but this doesn't mean you'll have zero errors. This is just a mathematical limit that tends to something realistic as very high frequencies will not be so different from infinite frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

You have to differentiate between resolution, reproducibility and noise. Resolution can typically be made smaller than reproducibility and noise, at which point improvements in resolution become meaningless. This, by the way, is not just true for actuators but it holds just as much for sensors and measurements in general.